# Computer Blue Screen then 3 Beeping noises on startup

Tags: windows-7, boot

I have a gateway desktop computer with windows 7
it was off for several months and I just decided to turn it on today
everything was running fine, I tried putting the password for my computer
and after a while it gave me a blue screen of death. I turned it off then
try to turn it on again and all I get are three beeping noises and that's it,
any clue on what might it be? I'm thinking its the BIOS but I don't know how to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

That's a **BIOS Code for Bad Memory**. Remove single sticks to narrow it down or swap them all out if nothing works.

Comment: thanks so much, so I had 4 GB of SDRAM and I just removed 2 sticks of 1GB each and the computer started-up just fine...will I ever be able to put them back in or does that means I will have to buy new ones?

Comment: Can't be absolutely certain, but usually if a Stick of RAM is dead it's dead. I can't imagine this being a temporary thing and it suddenly works again. Glad i could help.